# Primefaces Datatable Value as Checkbox Itemlabel

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am very new to java. In primefaces datatable, I'm trying to display "checkbox itemlabel" instead of "value". Here is my code;

<p:column headerText="Person Type" ><h:outputText value="#{persontbl.typeprs}" /></p:column>

#{persontbl.typeprs} holds "True" or "False" (checkbox). With this code in datatable, naturally I see the row value as "False" or "True".

But I want to see as **"Customer" if true**, **""(*blank*) if false**.

In previous (save) page, my checkbox is as below;

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{persontbl Service. persontbl.typeprs }" itemLabel="Customer" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy simply change your output to...

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{persontbl.typeprs ? 'Customer' : ''}" />
```